# how to write Date in a loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

Here's my dumb code which I think could have a simple way to write it in a for loop.
But I dont know how to make `i` as the year (2008-2014) of the date.
Thanks for your help.

BTW: I know this may seem too simple for some skilled R users, but not for me. So please do not minus the vote. Thanks for your kindness.

```
data3[,2][data3$Date<"2014-09-01" & data3$Date>"2014-08-01"]<-NA
data3[,2][data3$Date<"2013-09-01" & data3$Date>"2013-08-01"]<-NA
data3[,2][data3$Date<"2012-09-01" & data3$Date>"2012-08-01"]<-NA
data3[,2][data3$Date<"2011-09-01" & data3$Date>"2011-08-01"]<-NA
data3[,2][data3$Date<"2010-09-01" & data3$Date>"2010-08-01"]<-NA
data3[,2][data3$Date<"2009-09-01" & data3$Date>"2009-08-01"]<-NA
data3[,2][data3$Date<"2008-09-01" & data3$Date>"2008-08-01"]<-NA
```

Comment: Is `data3$Date` a date, or a character string? What is the result of `class(data3$Date)`??

Comment: @jlhoward - while not ideal, as long as the date format is Y-m-d, then these sorts of comparisons should work okay. E.g. `"2014-09-01" < "2014-09-02"` returns `TRUE`

Comment: @thelatemail Right, but the answer to OP's question is different depending on the class of `data3$Date`

Comment: @jlhoward it's Date. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
indx1 <- seq(as.Date('2008-08-01'), length.out=7, by='1 year')
indx2 <- seq(as.Date('2008-09-01'), length.out=7, by='1 year')
data3[,2] <- data3[,2]*(Reduce(`&`,Map(function(x,y) {
                     data3[,2][x < data3[,1] & data3[,1] < y] <- NA
                     data3[,2]},
                     indx1, indx2)))
```

Or

```
data3[unlist(Map(function(x,y,z) which(y <x & x < z) ,
                 list(data3[,1]), indx1, indx2)),2] <- NA
```

Or using a `for` loop

```
 l1 <- vector('list', length(indx1))
 for(i in seq_along(indx1)){
     l1[[i]] <- which(indx1[i] < data3[,1] & data3[,1] < indx2[i])
  }

 data3[unlist(l1),2] <- NA
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data3 <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date('2008-07-01'), length.out=150,
                         by='20 days'), val=rnorm(150))
```